# Loading in Images via jQuery prepend But After Other images Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am prepending an image to a div that contains another image. This is allowing me to get a transition between the two images on hover.

**Problem:**
The problem is that the image that is supposed to be hidden underneath, the dynamically loaded ones, is loading first and displays. Is there a way to load the image via jQuery after everything has been loaded? If not that, can I hide the image until everything is loaded then display it?

**Javascript**:

```
  (function($) {
  if ($('#bottom-art-jason').length) return; // only add once
    
        var jsonArt = '<img id="bottom-art-jason" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5fbc13ab28cdca2d92d13045/t/5fbd6f1fc40cee429f55218e/1606250271337/Jason_Art.jpg" class="thumb-image loaded" style="left: 0%; top: -1.76471%; width: 100%; height: 103.529%; position: absolute;"/>';

    $('#block-2091ad01016e0c16fbf5 .image-block-wrapper').prepend(jsonArt);
})(jQuery);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="image-block-wrapper">
     <img class="thumb-image top" 
src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5cae826d21d24e00012dc02b/t/5e0a26c2afc7590ba0a3b443/1603914016365/Jason-5941.jpg">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#block-2091ad01016e0c16fbf5 {
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#block-2091ad01016e0c16fbf5 img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#block-2091ad01016e0c16fbf5 img.loaded:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: Just to be entirely clear, do you want the image already on the page to load first, or do you want the dynamically added one to load first?

Comment: The image already on the page should load first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `load` event.
*For Example:*

```
var loaded = false;
firstIMG.on("load", ()=>{
if(!loaded){
var secondIMG = '<img id="bottom-art-jason" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5fbc13ab28cdca2d92d13045/t/5fbd6f1fc40cee429f55218e/1606250271337/Jason_Art.jpg" class="thumb-image loaded" style="left: 0%; top: -1.76471%; width: 100%; height: 103.529%; position: absolute;"/>';
$('#block-2091ad01016e0c16fbf5 .image-block-wrapper').prepend(secondsIMG);
loaded = true;
};
});
```

Comment: This worked, I also had to set the opacity to 1 for the items in order to avoid an initial fade-in effect.